# SQL: Query 1 without Query 2

Tags: sql, filter, where-clause

I'm trying to write a query where I take what's left of a First Subquery and take everything of the Second one out, so basically (from the example below) speaking Q1 - Q2 = 121 - 7 = 114 (ParticipantID's that are on Q1 and not in Q2)

```
select ParticipantID
 from
 (
 Query 1 results (121 in my case)
 ) AS Q1
 Join 
 (
 Query 2 results (7)
 ) AS Q2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `NOT IN` predicate :

```
select ParticipantID
from
(
   -- Query 1 results
) AS Q1
WHERE ParticipantID NOT IN(
                           -- SELECT ParticipantID 
                           -- FROM Query 2 results
                          )
```

Or, `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT ...
FROM
(
   --- Query 1 results
) AS Q1
LEFT JOIN
(
   -- Query 2 
) AS Q2 ON ... -- JOIN condition here
WHERE Q2.ParticipantID IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Q1.ParticipantID from (query1) as Q1 where Q1.ParticipantID NOT IN (select participantID from query2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT IN` :

```
SELECT * FROM Q1
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT ParticipantID FROM Q2)
```

Or use `EXCEPT` (or `MINUS`, depending on DB engine) :

```
SELECT ParticipantID FROM Q1
EXCEPT
SELECT ParticipantID FROM Q2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are usig Sql server:

You can use:

[Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188055.aspx):
EXCEPT returns any distinct values from the left query that are not also found on the right query.

Syntax

```
{ <query_specification> | ( <query_expression> ) } 
{ EXCEPT | INTERSECT }
{ <query_specification> | ( <query_expression> ) }
```

Eg:

```
SELECT ParticipantID
FROM Q1
EXCEPT
SELECT ParticipantID
FROM Q2;
```